# Cannot create cloudbees project using eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, cloudbees

I'm trying to follow [CloudBees Toolkit for Eclipse How-to Guide](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Documentation/CloudBeesEclipseToolkit) to create a Hello World on cloudbees using a brand new Eclipse Juno that I just set up (with Subclipse). I have also followed step 3 to "Create a new SVN repository on CloudBees".

I'm up to step 4 where I was trying to create a new Project but when I'm the step to create new Jenkins job, there was a warning that says "Enable hosting in Forge to configure Jenkins job SCM automatically". If I next select to Host at Forge SVN, I can an empty repository combobox which I can't move on.

Anything that I missed out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try again now - there was a unexpected regression in one of our internal APIs.